# LDAP integration is not working in ejabbered

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ejabberd

We deployed one ejabbered server and it is working fine with default admin@localhost user. But the LDAP integration is not working in my case. As per the documentation, Put the followings in my ejabberd.yml file to integrate our LDAP server

> auth_method: [ldap] ldap_servers: ["ds1.test.com"] ldap_encrypt: none
>   ldap_port: 389 ldap_rootdn: "cn=admin,dc=ds1,dc=test,dc=com"
>   ldap_password: "********" ldap_base:
>   "ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds1,dc=test,dc=com" ldap_uids: ["mail"]

Getting the following error in its log when I try to login into it using my LDAP account

*2018-02-28 11:02:30.912 [warning] <0.641.0>@ejabberd_web_admin:process:239 Access of <<"joe@abc.com">> from <<"::FFFF:1.12.50.5">> failed with error: <<"inexistent-account">>*

Answer (score 0):

This warning does not means your LDAP connection isn't working. Actually, if this is the only warning, it means the LDAP connection was successfull.

I will need more informations :

- Can you show me all the logs when ejabberd starts ?
- Can you also paste me your hosts part and your 'Access control lists'
  part of the yml configuration ?